# Infimum of Function

Tags: proof-verification, normal-distribution

How can I show that $$\inf_{z>0}\{z^{-1}(z\mu+0.5z^2\sigma^2-\ln(\alpha)\} = \mu+\sigma\sqrt{-2\ln(\alpha)}\quad ?$$

$\alpha \in\ ]0,1]$

Think I'm probably doing something wrong when computing the infimun.

The original full proof I want to do is to show that 
$\inf_{z>0}\{z^{-1}(\ln(\frac{E[e^{zX}]}{\alpha}))\}= \mu+\sigma\sqrt{-2\ln(\alpha)}$ for $X$ normally distributed $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Comment: Is $\alpha>1$? I think you are missing some hypotheses.

Comment: just added the hyphotesis, thank you!

Comment: I guess the beginning "$z^-1$"ctually mean $z^{-1}$? And if $\alpha<1$ you can just take derivative  to see a unique minimum.

Comment: Unless I'm doing some stupid mistake, I get sigma in my denominator and not in the numerator: $\mu+\frac{\sqrt{-2ln(\alpha)}}{\sigma}$

Answer (score 1):

From $AM\geq GM$ we get that for $a,b,z>0$, we have $\frac{1}{2}\left(az+\frac{b}{z}\right)\geq \sqrt{(az)\frac{b}{z}}$, or equivalently, $$az+\frac{b}{z}\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$$
In particular
 $\mu+0.5\sigma^2 z+\frac{-\ln(\alpha)}{z}\geq \mu+2\sqrt{0.5\sigma^2(-\ln\alpha)}=\mu+\sigma\sqrt{-2\ln\alpha}$.